# Number field that deletes non-numbers without clearing previous numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '')">
```

I use it to prevent the user from entering anything except a number into a field on my page. However, I noticed that if the user types a number first but then accidentally hits a non-number key, the field is cleared and they have to start over. This may cause frustration so I was wondering if there was a way to tweak the code so that it does not do this, or if there was a similar method I could use. I am limited to JavaScript, JQuery, and HTML. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean; it works fine for me. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behavior. Nevertheless, this is bad UI design. You should allow the user to enter whatever it wants (letters, symbols) and then run a validation for a number. The current kind of treatment can have unexpected side-effects (as you describe) and, worse, may leave some users disturbed, even angry, because when they type, their keyboard won't work ("damn website!", they shout). Believe me, this is way more frequent than the most of us thinks it is.

Comment: I got rid of the code above and ended up using a JS funtion. I hope this helps someone with the same issue!

$("#medianSalary").keydown(
                                    function(event) {
                                                  if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                                                        event.preventDefault();}
                                    });
});

Comment: Meh, there's no reason to allow a user to enter known-bad data. If I was doing client-side validation anyway, why let someone enter a letter for a US Social Security Number? There's no reason to delay feedback--as long as there's feedback, e.g., a fading warning about accepting only digits etc.

Comment: @user3784596 I think you should validate the value after filling the form. There are easy ways to do that.
Like you can use `input type number`.

What is problem with that?

Comment: I did that at first but that the request of the client I had to simply not allow anything else in the field to be typed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue. I got rid of the code above and ended up using a JS function. I put in within my $(Document).ready(function() I hope this helps someone with the same problem!

```
$("#medianSalary").keydown( function(event) { if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) { event.preventDefault();} }); });
```